# Javascript fetch group total results by key

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch, key

I'm performing a javascript fetch where I'm returning a json from a GET response and I'd need to group by the total amount of occurrences for each category (my keys).
Here's an example of my json:

```
[{Id, Var1, Var2, CreationDate},
{1, 123, abc123, 2020-12-11},
{2, 1234, abc123, 2020-12-12},
{3, 12345, abc123, 2020-12-12},
{4, 1234, abc123, 2020-12-13},
{5, 321, cda123, 2020-12-15},
{6, 3214, cda123, 2020-12-15},
{7, 5432, fff123, 2020-12-16},
{8, 5432, fff123, 2020-12-16},
{9, 5432, fff123, 2020-12-16},
{10, 5432, fff123, 2020-12-16},
{11, 5432, ddd123, 2020-12-16},
{12, 5432, ddd123, 2020-12-16},
{13, 5432, ddd123, 2020-12-16},]
```

I'd like to group by the returning result by key, where key is "Var2" and it is part of the values I have in the array. To match it just need to contains one of the values in the listOfVariables array.
here's my code:

```
var myObj;
var result;
var listOfVariables = [abc, cda, fff, ddd];
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?listOfVariables')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>myObj= data)
.then(() =>
    myObj.forEach(function (elem){
        var variable = elem.Var2.includes(listOfVariables);
        if (result[variable ]) {
                result[variable ] += 1;
            } else {
                result[variable ] = 1;
            }
    });
    listOfVariables.forEach(variable => {
            if(!result.hasOwnProperty(variable )) {
                finalResult[variable ] = 0;
            } else {
                finalResult[variable ] = result[variable ];
            }
    });
```

the final result I get is:

```
[abc: 0
 cda: 0,
 fff: 0,
 ddd, 0]
```

but it should be:

```
[abc: 4,
cda: 2,
fff: 4,
ddd: 3]
```

where am I wrong? Apparently my code can't understand if the variables contains, as a substring, one of the elements of the array lisrOfVariables.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const result = [];
const finalResult = [];
const listOfVariables = ['abc', 'cda', 'fff', 'ddd'];

fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?listOfVariables')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => data.forEach((elem) => {
    const variable = elem.Var2;
    const variableInList = listOfVariables.includes(variable);

    if (variableInList) {
      result[variable] = (result[variable] || 0) + 1;
    }
  }));

listOfVariables.forEach(variable => {
  finalResult[variable] = result.hasOwnProperty(variable) ? result[variable] : 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! What happens if my Var2 is way longer than listOfVariables? For instance Var2 is 'ddd1234' but the equivalent element in listOfVariables is 'ddd'. Currently everything is failing because of this issue